# How do I get the text of the radio button selected item?

Tags: c#, radio-button

Here are my radio buttons

```
Runescape
Maplestory
League
```

So this is my current method and it runs perfectly fine.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are playing Runescape.");
    }

    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are playing Maplestory.");
    }

    else if (radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are playing League.");
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way I can print out the SelectedItem kinda like a combo box. Basically, the text of the radio button.

Combobox version:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are playing " + comboBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Something along the lines of this (not sure if it is possible).

```
MessageBox.Show("You are playing " + RadioButton.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `Text`  property of `RadioButton` .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing "+radioButton1.Text);
        }

        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing Maplestory "+"+radioButton2.Text);
        }

        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing League "+"+radioButton3.Text);
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:**  there is no `SelectedItem` Property for `RadioButton` control.

but you can create a `function` which will return the `Name` of the selected `RadioButton`

Try this:

```
    private String getSelectedRadioButtonName()
     {
            foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if (c is RadioButton && ((RadioButton) c).Checked==true)
                {
                    return c.Text;
                }
            }
            return "No Game";
      }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            MessageBox.Show("You are playing "+getSelectedRadioButtonName());
    }
```

Comment: Can I make it so it doesn't use if statements? Like similar to the combo box (updated code)

Comment: @puretppc : there is no `SelectedItem` property in RadioButton but you can create a function which will serve your purpose see my edited answer with section `solution2`.

Comment: @puretppc : see the complete edited answer in `solution2` mark it as answer if you dont mind :)

Comment: I just checked it and I realized that it will always seem to return "No game" even on any radio button checked. At the start of the program, I have at 1 radio button checked

Comment: @puretppc: have you put your radio buttons on some panel?

Comment: @puretppc: then you need to change `this.Controls` to `groupBox1.Controls` in foreach loop, see my edited answer it works perfectly :)

Comment: @puretppc : You are Welcome :) glad to be help of you.