# How to use the multiple radio buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

How can I use multiple radio buttons and save to my database access the select item text radio button he save only the gender when I try only from name to gender.when i try query insert into (lname, mname, fname, course, major, minor, gender) he save the data in my database access when I try the year with another radio buttons insert into (lname, mname, fname, course, major, minor, gender, year) he error to the insert into but he save the text when I leave the text in the string year.

Design of my form:

[image]

```
public partial class student : UserControl
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = 
    Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source 
    =C:\Users\ronaldcaymo\Desktop\Student Information System.accdb");
    string Gender;
    string year;
    string Status;

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into 
        table1(Lname,Fname,Mname,Course,Major,Minor,semester,Gender,Status) 
        values('"+tblname.Text+"','"+tbfname.Text+"','"+tbmname.Text+ 
        "','"+cbcourse.Text+"','" +cbmajor.Text 
  +"','"+cbminor.Text+"','"+cbsemester.Text+"','"+Gender+"','"+Status+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Student Added");
    }    
    private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gender = "Male";
    }

    private void radioButton6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gender ="Female";
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        year = "1st";
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        year ="2nd";
    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        year ="3rd";
    }

    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        year ="4th";
    }

    private void radioButton8_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Status = "Single";
    }

    private void radioButton7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Status = "Married";
    }  

}
```

Comment: "_save only the gender when i try only from name to gender._" I understand that English is perhaps not your native language, but unfortunately i don't understand what you are trying to say about your problem. :-( Do not try clarifying your problem here in the comments. Rather, **edit** and improve your question to expand the problem description and make it clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: If your form is as shown, then you have not enabled any of the radio buttons - you should set one button to enabled in each set if you want a default value.

Comment: Consider using google translator if you struggle to translate your problem because it's hard to understand what you want to achieve or what your issue here right now due to your english level.

Comment: when i try query insert into (lname,mname,fname,course,major,minor,gender) he save the data in my database access when i try the year with another radio buttons nsert into (lname,mname,fname,course,major,minor,gender,year)  he error to the insert into but he save the text when i leave the text in the string year and the status too

Comment: i edit sir @elgonzo

Comment: @newb why don't you use use the property `Text` of your radiobuttons combined with a simple condition check to verifiy of the radio button is selected, read their text and use it directly instead. Check out this for example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308619/how-do-i-get-the-text-of-the-radio-button-selected-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CheckedChanged`event of your radio buttons will trigger everytime your radio button's status is changed, that means when it's checked or unchecked.

So when '1st year' is checked and you check another radio button such as '3rd year', '1st year' will become unchecked and thus trigger the event `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` at the same time with `radioButton3_CheckedChanged`.

To fix this issue, add a condition check inside all your `radioButton_CheckedChanged` events as such:

```
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioButton3.Checked){
        year ="3rd";
    }
}
```